# Why are there separate copies of the Terms of Service per site, if the link in each site just goes to Stack Overflow's version?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, legal, footer, terms-of-service

I noticed that each site in the network has its own copy of the Terms of Service, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service, https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service, https://travel.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service, etc.

But the link to the terms in the footer of each site just goes to Stack Overflow's version, not the local per-site copy.

In the past, there used to be a single copy of the terms on stackexchange.com, but since the terms were recently changed in May 2018, the current arrangement of having a copy on each site was adopted.

What's the point of having a copy of the terms on each site if the footer link just goes to Stack Overflow's version?

(Side note: the old link to the terms hosted on stackexchange.com now redirects to Stack Overflow's version as well.)