# Each site's moderator agreement - privacy policy linked to stack overflow page instead of the site's own page

Tags: support, bug, legal, privacy

On every Stack Exchange site except Stack Overflow, in the [Moderator Agreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) (`<sitename.com>/legal/moderator-agreement`) page's **The agreement** section contains two links.

The first link is pointing to the specific site's [Terms of Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) (`<sitename.com>/legal/terms-of-service`) page, but the second link is pointing to the Stack Overflow's [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) (`https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy`) page.

Since each site has its own Privacy Policy page, and the first link is already pointing to the current site's terms of service page, why is the second link all the sites pointing to Stack Overflow's page?

Is this intentional or wrongly linked to Stack Overflow's page?

Screenshot from the agreement section:

> [image: The agreement]

Comment: Seems like the same issue as [Why are there separate copies of the Terms of Service per site, if the link in each site just goes to Stack Overflow's version?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319805/why-are-there-separate-copies-of-the-terms-of-service-per-site-if-the-link-in-e)