# Should the legal page on stackoverflow.com actually be on stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, legal, terms-of-service

I have seen plenty of references to the legal disclaimers etc. for the whole Stack Exchange site being referred to https://stackoverflow.com/legal/, but all SE sites are owned and operated by Stack Exchange, Inc. not anyone called Stack Overflow, (Ltd., LLC, PLC, Inc. or otherwise).

> The Stack Overflow Network is a set of related Internet sites and other applications for questions and answers (also referred to herein as the “Network”), owned and operated by Stack Exchange, Inc.

Going to https://stackexchange.com/legal/ redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/legal/, but should the Public Network Terms of Service, including *Disclaimer of Warranties* and *Limitation of Liability* etc. be moved to https://stackexchange.com/legal/ and all SE legal pages e.g. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/legal/ be redirected to https://stackexchange.com/legal/?

Not only does this centralize the legals to the right company website, but when and if the legals need editing, there is one point of call for those edits.

Comment: See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9024/295232): *The company is legally named Stack Exchange, Inc. It uses the brand name Stack Overflow.*

Comment: In casual conversation, I refer to *Stack Exchange* when talking about the collection of sites. I only mention *Stack Overflow* when referencing *a specific site* on the network. In fact, I consider the use of *Stack Overflow* to refer to all sites as misleading and confusing.

Comment: Related: [Why are there separate copies of the Terms of Service per site, if the link in each site just goes to Stack Overflow's version?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319805/377214)

Comment: It's probably a matter of taste. All the given links are websites of the company.